# App Store Rejection 18.2

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

We developed a sporting app with a social media side to it. There is a news feed where you are able to upload photo's and link YouTube videos.

Apple has rejected it twice for the same reason below (first rejection we understand)

After the first rejection we made changes as requested by Apple.

1. Modified our Terms and Conditions to state any objectionable content will be removed and the user might be banned.
2. Added a "Report" Post option that sends us a message of the "Objectionable Content" and we will then remove it within 24 hours.

> 18.2
>
> We found your app enables the display of user-generated content which may become sexually  explicit. Therefore we ask that you put the following precautions in place, to ensure your app remains in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, we were unable to find a flagging system found to report objectionable user generated content and images that could be uploaded to the app.
>
> - Use Moderators to flag and remove inappropriate content
> - Require that your users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must be clear that there's no  tolerance for objectionable content
> - Users need a way to flag or report objectionable content and/or users generating this content
> - Developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content  and ejecting the user who provided the offending content
> - Developer needs a method for ejecting users who violate the terms of the EULA

If anyone has had a similar experience kindly share as we cant understand what else they want.

We have sent a message to them in the resolution center but got no reply.

Comment: what is the rating you have given to the app? 4+? or the one with alert of "are you 17 yrs of age and above?"

Comment: We rated it 4+ did not feel we needed 17+

Comment: This is a question for the review team, not stack overflow.

Comment: if the review team would answer, but i have tried numerous time and get no reply!

Comment: There is an option in your developer account to write a message to them.  They always responded in my case.

Comment: Thanks borrrden I will try submit a message to them thru that avenue as the resolution center does not work.

Comment: We're starting an Area 51 proposal for these kind of questions: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54103/app-stores?referrer=Znmz97Ak7ERjuiuCuAdO9A2

Comment: @kara,@Ricky Ferreira, I have same feedback from apple. in my app, I am showing user input description and add images. so please suggest what I need to add.  -- Apple points->
- Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content.
- A method for filtering objectionable content.
- A mechanism for users to flag objectionable content.
- The ability to block abusive users from the service. 
- The developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content and ejecting the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a method (mechanism) to the app for users to tell you that they don't like some piece of content. Like a button to send a message to you, with a description of what they don't like. If multiple people report the same item you would usually want that item to be automatically removed from display in the app.

Comment: We have added a "Report" Button which does exactly that and it will rejected again.

Comment: In that case you need to add the rating and EULA to fully notify users of the risk that some objectionable material may be found in the app and what they can do about it. It's about visibility - you need to be fully transparent with the user and Apple needs to see you doing it.

Comment: I will try again by adding the 17+ rating (how does Facebook get a 4+ rating? ) we already have the mention of the objectionable content in the app and when creating a account for the first time we force you to accept the terms and conditions.

Answer (score 4):

1) You need to provide some way to flag the content as objectionable, and at the server end let a moderator view the same content. If it breaks the guidelines, then the moderator can delete the content and suspend the user; the relevant content should be hidden from app users.

2) Also clearly mention these guidelines in the terms and conditions, so that nobody can upload data to the server without accepting them.